# Why is SORT(UNIQUE()) not ordering correctly when data is added? OR Why are tables not following cell format?

Tags: sorting, excel-formula, formatting

I'm attempting to sort a list of numerical codes from data in a table using this formula:`=SORT(UNIQUE(B3:B43)))`. However, when I add data to the the table, it sorts incorrectly.

Using example data, this results in this:

[image: A column of seven Excel cells, top-to-bottom, showing 7000 right-aligned, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, and 6000 left-aligned.]

Calculating the `UNIQUE(B3:B43)` part of the formula results in `=SORT({"1000";"2000";"3000";"4000";"5000";"6000";7000})`. The lack of quotation marks around 7000 makes me think it's reading data added later (as I did with 7000, added to the table after the table and formula were made) as 'General' type, meaning it's considered a number, rather than defaulting to the 'Text'. However, in the table the cell is left-aligned, and shows the type as 'Text'.

I'm mainly wondering why it's happening but my attempt to fix it using `TEXT()` failing rather spectacularly: `=SORT(UNIQUE(TEXT(B3:B43, "Text")))` results in this:

[image: A column of seven Excel cells, all left-aligned, containing, top-to-bottom; "T1902xt", "T1905xt", "T1908xt", "T1910xt", "T1913xt", "T1916xt", "T1919xt".]

It seems to be replacing "e" with... something.

---

**Immediate Edit:**

Working on it while writing this, I tried changing the cell format of the table column between 'Text', 'General' and 'Number' a few times. The cells didn't immediately update, but going onto the first entry (a "1000") made it a number. I changed it back, but the `SORT` is now showing a numerical 1000 and a text "1000" (meaning the cells now show 1000, 7000, "1000", "2000", "3000", "4000", "5000", "6000").

---

Ignoring, for the moment, the `TEXT()` bizarreness, I'm confused why my formula is refusing to follow cell formatting.

---

**Edit 2**
It's worth noting that in the table, all of the cells have the "Number  Stored As Text" note, apart from 7000 and the modified 1000.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshot, [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98kPX3qVscaYvrCKR?e=VORlgp) refer.

**Overview**

Ordinarily, Excel's 'sort' in ascending order will place number-formatted cells above those with text format (per [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2730-excel-sort-data-alphanumeric.html)).  You can try this the regular 'sort' feature - e.g. in main ribbon, Data -> Sort - where jumbled values returns the following:

[image: Result of regular sort]

(left aligned are formatted as text, i.e. with a leading single apostrophe, whilst right aligned are number formatted).

---

**Workaround**

One workaround is to use *sortby*, with a text version of the values:

```
=SORTBY(B2:B9,"'"&B2:B9)
```

[image: Sortby workaround]

This would be 'safer' than sorting by number formatted values, e.g. with a multiplier of 1, in case some of your cells contain both numbers *and* text, such as A101, B202, etc.)

---

**Note**

RE: unique- this can simply used as a wrapper around the entire equation for simplicity (the alternative being to use unique twice within the sortby formula, which is clearly a less favourable solution in regards to simplicity/parsimony, and problem error-rate too)..

```
=UNIQUE(SORTBY(B2:B9,"'"&B2:B9))
```

Comment: @DukeNukem - ta.